# Mongoose return duplicate key for new data

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, uuid

My issues are I am writing a script to store JSON on the database server by post request.
There are such issues:

for the first time, every JSON is submitted successfully when the server is restarted.
after that, no JSON data will be submitted and give mongoose duplicate id issue.

```
E11000 duplicate key error index: [database_name].[collection].$_id_ dup key: { : "2c73c49d-8ad2-49bf-b5a1-520aa595df17" }
```

- a key generated by schemas like

```
new Schema({
  _id: { type: String, default: uuidv4() },
  ... // remainings
}
```

- Post request call back is here

```
function (req, res) {
    models
     .create({'---': req.body.---, ..., ..., ..., ...})
     .then(result => res.json(result))
     .catch(err => {
       res.send(err.message);
     });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`default` parameter should be a function

If you pass `uuidv4()` it will pass a generated value when creating the Schema, and will use that value for all documents.

The schema should be defined like this.

```js
new Schema({
  _id: { type: String, default: uuidv4 },
  ... // remainings
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can follow this code**

```
async function (req, res) {
   const _doc=await models.create(req.body)
    res.send(_doc)
}
```